# Can you assign a TypeConverter without a TypeConverterAttribute?

Tags: c#, typeconverter

Dependency requirements are forcing me to have a class and its TypeConverter in different 
assemblies.

Is there a way to assign a TypeConverter to a class without using a TypeConverterAttribute, and thus causing circular assembly references.

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Hmm, not sure I've seen this before, but you could add the TypeConverterAttribute at runtime using a TypeDescriptor, so given my sample classes:

```
public class MyType
{
    public string Name;
}

public class MyTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            return true;

        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value.GetType() == typeof(string))
            return new MyType() { Name = (string) value };

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

I could then have a method:

```
public void AssignTypeConverter<IType, IConverterType>()
{
  TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(IType), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(IConverterType)));
}

AssignTypeConverter<MyType, MyTypeConverter>();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This however, **does not work for XAML**, since XAML does not take component modifications at runtime into account. I [found a way around this](https://whathecode.wordpress.com/2015/02/14/generic-typeconverter/) using a `TypeConverter` which redirects its implementation to a converter loaded using `TypeDescriptor`.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `TypeConverterAttribute` and use its constructor which accepts a fully qualified name. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56x5sxad.aspx).

Comment: Wouldn't that still necessitate referencing the assembly containing the typeconverter?

Comment: No, assembly containing the typeconverter would be loaded in runtime via Type.GetType (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx).

Comment: @Spike, no, because the type converter type can be referenced by name rather than typeof(...).

Comment: And how to actually assign a `TypeConverter` to a class? Just instantiating a `TypeConverter` class changes nothing if I understand things correctly...