# Expand custom object in property grid without any modifications to the class?

Tags: c#, vb.net, propertygrid

By default, custom objects are grayed out, and not expandable:

[image]

I know it's possible to make them expandable using [ExpandableObjectConverter](http://www.bluevisionsoftware.com/WebSite/TipsAndTricksDetails.aspx?Name=ExpandableObjectConverter), but that requires extending the original class.

What if I cannot modify the original class? Is there a generic approach of handling custom object expansion inside a property grid?

Comment: Perhaps the same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068453/can-you-assign-a-typeconverter-without-a-typeconverterattribute)?

Comment: This is a great workaround! It still requires manually associating types with their converters, but it's only one line of code per each type for basic expansion support. Thank you very much for finding this gem! You can publish something as an answer to be accepted, perhaps including a minimum reproducible example. Or just vote to close as a duplicate (although I feel like the link is a superset of this task, i.e. a more generic one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically add the `TypeConverterAttribute` for the `ExpandableObjectConverter` at runtime, using something like the following (VB.NET).

```vb
Dim attr = New TypeConverterAttribute(GetType(ExpandableObjectConverter))
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(GetType(ExtensionDataObject), attr)
```

You would need to `AddAttribute` for each type you want to be expandable. If the types are all in a specific namespace, you could use reflection to find them:

```vb
Dim assm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() ' or some other assembly
For Each t In assm.GetTypes().Where(Function(x) x.Namespace = "InterestingTypes")
    TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(t, attr)
Next
```

(sorry for the broken syntax highlighting - I should have used C#!)

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the syntax highlight. +1 and accepting.

Comment: @Neolisk Thanks - I was searching for some way to specify the language but couldn't find it!