# Expand collection in property grid without any modifications to the class?

Tags: c#, vb.net, propertygrid, typedescriptor

This approach works for everything but collections:

- [Expand custom object in property grid without any modifications to the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151066/expand-custom-object-in-property-grid-without-any-modifications-to-the-class)

Collections are displayed like this:

[image]

So even though they are expandable, there isn't much use for them inside property grid.

Here is an example of what I am looking for (screenshot taken from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert)):

[image]

The linked article also contains some code, which would make this happen, but it **requires modifying the original class**. Between it and my previous question, I came up with some ideas, but I'm not very fluent in using `System.ComponentModel` namespace.

Here is a reduced test case (custom class with one property of collection type, which contains one object of custom type, which has one string property):

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

  Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.AssignTypeConverter(Of MyCustomClassCollection, ExpandableObjectConverter)()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim collection As New MyCustomClassCollection
    collection.Add(New MyCustomClass With {.MyCustomProperty = "Hello"})

    Dim container As New MyCustomClassCollectionContainer(collection)

    Me.PropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = container
  End Sub

  Private Sub AssignTypeConverter(Of IType, IConverterType)()
    System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(GetType(IType),
      New System.ComponentModel.TypeConverterAttribute(GetType(IConverterType)))
  End Sub

End Class


Public Class MyCustomClass
  Public Property MyCustomProperty As String
End Class

Public Class MyCustomClassCollection : Inherits System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of MyCustomClass)
End Class

Public Class MyCustomClassCollectionContainer

  Dim _items As MyCustomClassCollection

  Public ReadOnly Property Items As MyCustomClassCollection
    Get
      Return _items
    End Get
  End Property

  Sub New(items As MyCustomClassCollection)
    _items = items
  End Sub

End Class
```

Proposed solution (pseudo-code, does not compile)

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MyCustomClassTypeDescriptor : Inherits ExpandableObjectConverter

  Public Overrides Function GetProperties(context As ITypeDescriptorContext,
                                value As Object, attributes() As Attribute) _
                                            As PropertyDescriptorCollection
    Dim pds As New PropertyDescriptorCollection(Nothing)
    Dim lst As IList(Of Object) = DirectCast(value, IList)
    For i As Integer = 0 To lst.Count - 1
      Dim item As MyCustomClass = DirectCast(lst.Item(i), MyCustomClass)
      'compile error - abstract class cannot be instantiated
      Dim pd As New PropertyDescriptor(item)
      pds.Add(pd)
    Next
    Return pds
  End Function

End Class
```

And then apply this custom object converter at runtime.

Is it going to work like this? What am I missing? Any suggestions are welcome!

**Note:** The above is VB.NET, but if you speak C#, feel free to use it.

Comment: are you wanting to add/remove items in the collection? if so you will need a CollectionEditor and several pieces to handle designer serialization.  I am not entirely sure what you are up to, but you might also be able to write a CollectionEditor then assign it to the existing collection you dont have access to via: `System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.AddEditorTable`

Comment: @Plutonix: I only need to view existing collection items, and be able to edit their properties. I don't need to add new or delete collection items in the property grid. Could you please elaborate on your suggestion?

Comment: Interesting.  When I use the code from the linked question, applying the `TypeConverterAttribute` for the `ExpandableObjectConverter` to both the class containing the collection, and the class contained in the collection, I don't get the expander - it also just has `(collection)` for the value, but if I click on the `...` button next to the item, I get a nice collection editor!  I am just using `List(Of MyType)` for the collection though, so that is probably the difference.

Comment: IF/when VB/VS sees a valid collection it will launch the std Collection Editor, **that** class has some problems though for the changes to be saved, items to be created and such.  If the real underlying class (no idea what it looks like) is not setup to persist items or doesnt have the required TypeConverters for designer serialization, you could try adding them too, but I am not sure it would work.  just as you added the Expander attribute, you can write an Editor and assign it to a Type in a similar fashion.  I have had problems getting this to work when there is a default editor assigned.

Comment: @Mark List<T> is almost certainly the difference - for those you dont need anything at all in the way if Attributes etc because it is a collection container with all the requisites (`Item`/Accessor and `Add`) exposed.  Its more work to STOP it from launching.

Comment: @Plutonix: I am trying to avoid using default collection editor (even if it's there - ignore it), and instead have it expandable all in one property grid, for convenience reasons. This is partially because collections can have other collections inside them, and having like 5 property grids on top of one another is impossible to manage. Don't ask me why we have objects with hierarchy like this. :)

Comment: Just tried it with a custom subclass of `Collection` and it worked the same... but your last reply to Plutonix is the key.  What I am seeing is the default collection editor (separate window), which is not what you want, so just ignore my babbling!

Comment: @Mark: Yeah, using collection editor is not a problem. I just hope there is a way of getting it to display all in one property grid. You can check the screenshot above - example with a collection of employees. Whether there is a collection editor button to the right - does not matter.

Comment: The thing is that the CP article you linked to **is** a collection editor.  You could write one which does not allow adding new items, then add it to the EditorTable.  What is unknown is if the class you are working with is setup to handle all the little things required (like designer persistence) and  some of those things cant be added in reflection.  Would it be possible to subclass the thing you want to extend?

Comment: @Plutonix: Oops, I linked the wrong article - now fixed, please check again (had too many tabs open at the time of research). The class in question is not set up to work with designer, pretty much as in the reduced test case above. No, I cannot subclass it.

Comment: I think you are out of luck. That article seems to be about designing the class from the ground up to do what you want.  And I think (tl;dr) that is for editing the Employees at runtime, not in design time which comes with a different set of requirements and require adding a lot of attributes and such via reflection.  Mark gravell is a wizard (IMO) at all things TypeDescriptor related if you could figure out how to get his attention.

Comment: @Plutonix: But that's exactly what I need - edit the class at **runtime**.

Comment: Sorry, the old link to the collection editor is still stuck in my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long to continue in the comments, but how about something like this - a custom `ExpandableObjectConverter` that turns each collection item into a property (ItemX), and a custom property descriptor that gets the appropriate item.

```vb
Public Class MyCollectionTypeDescriptor(Of TColl As Collection(Of TItem), TItem)
    Inherits ExpandableObjectConverter

    Public Overrides Function GetProperties(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, value As Object, attributes() As Attribute) As PropertyDescriptorCollection
        Dim coll = DirectCast(value, TColl)
        Dim props(coll.Count - 1) As PropertyDescriptor
        For i = 0 To coll.Count - 1
            props(i) = New MyCollectionPropertyDescriptor(Of TColl, TItem)("Item" & CStr(i))
        Next
        Return New PropertyDescriptorCollection(props)
    End Function

End Class

Public Class MyCollectionPropertyDescriptor(Of TColl, TItem)
    Inherits PropertyDescriptor

    Private _index As Integer = 0

    Public Sub New(name As String)
        MyBase.New(name, Nothing)
        Dim indexStr = Regex.Match(name, "\d+$").Value
        _index = CInt(indexStr)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function CanResetValue(component As Object) As Boolean
        Return False
    End Function

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ComponentType As Type
        Get
            Return GetType(TColl)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function GetValue(component As Object) As Object
        Dim coll = DirectCast(component, Collection(Of TItem))
        Return coll(_index)
    End Function

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property IsReadOnly As Boolean
        Get
            Return True
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property PropertyType As Type
        Get
            Return GetType(TItem)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Sub ResetValue(component As Object)

    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub SetValue(component As Object, value As Object)

    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ShouldSerializeValue(component As Object) As Boolean
        Return False
    End Function

End Class
```

You can associate everything to your classes using:

```vb
Me.AssignTypeConverter(Of MyCustomClass, ExpandableObjectConverter)()
Me.AssignTypeConverter(Of MyCustomClassCollection, MyCollectionTypeDescriptor(Of MyCustomClassCollection, MyCustomClass))()
```

That should list each item in the main property grid, and each item will be expandable inline.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Hmm, I probably should have read the [linked article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert), which is quite similar and would have saved some work! :-)

Comment: It appears that my collection is being serialized as a list when going through the web service, so I changed `As Collection(Of TItem)` -> `IList`. Otherwise worked great, thank you for a perfect answer! +1 and accepting.